# Targeting Multiple Cells Simultaneously

Tags: vba, excel

I have a project where I have random range selection for the user.

Everything works when performed on a single selection. If the user selects more than one selection, it only runs the code for the first selection. I want to run for all the selected cells. I tried to use multiple selection and Application.Intersect Method but they didn't work.

```
Public A, B As Integer

Sub AutoLabel()
    A = 1
    B = 1
End Sub

'=======================================================

Sub LabelTest()

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        SR = .Row
        SC = .Column
        LR = SR + .Rows.Count - 1
        LC = SC + .Columns.Count - 1
    End With

    For Rcount = SR To LR
        For CCount = SC To LC
            Cells(Rcount, CCount).value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)
            A = A + 1
            If A = 5 Then A = 1: B = B + 1
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through each cell in your `Selection`, try the code below:

```
Sub LabelTest()

With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)
    A = A + 1
    If A = 5 Then A = 1: B = B + 1
Next Cell

End Sub
```

**Note**: in your declaration, it need to be `Public A As Integer, B As Integer`. Otherwise, only `B` will be defined as `Integer` and `A` will be defined as `Variant`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. But when I tried to run the code, it says, "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications. I think I will figure it out soon. But, if you have any idea on what is happening, please tell me.

Comment: @RainyDay how big is your selection ?

Comment: less than 10 cells per selection. I just selected two small selection to try the code but seems can't run.

Comment: @RainyDay you need to run `AutoLabel` before, right ? otherwise `A` and `B` never get initialized with values.

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with **Cells.value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)**

Comment: @RainyDay had a **Typo**, had `Cells` instead of `Cell`, try again the edited code, if it's working mark as "ANSWER" (click on the check mark next to my answer)

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you for the answer. You sure are my hero.